# Title of 1980s (?) sci-fi novel w/human appearing alien who can slow time and a panther

Tags: story-identification, novel

Could have been published in the 70s as well, story had an alien who comes to earth to destroy a MacGuffin for reasons although the MacGuffin also gives him great strength and the ability to increase his relative speed such that time is effectively slowed around him.

Not sure how/why but he first appears in a prison where he escapes by holding onto the under carriage of a car driven by a woman reporter/psychologist whom he then coerces into helping him.

There's another alien opposing him but it's in the form of a panther, I think.

He eventually destroys the MacGuffin, which removes his abilities right as he is attacked by the bad guy, so he dies. End of story.

Thanks for any assistance you can render!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall the cover art?  Any character or place names?  Did it take place in the US or somewhere non-specific?

Comment: Hmm, it does take place in the USA I am pretty sure. I feel like the main character has a super basic name (David... Craig... ) I don't recall the cover at at all. I think I either picked it up at a grocery store turnstile or a used book store...